# How to Edit User CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

So I've been trying to get an edit user functionality working in my app, and I'm a little confused as to how to go about doing this with CakePHP 3. This is what I've got for my edit action in my UsersController.php:

```
public function edit() {
    $this->layout = 'dashboard';

    $user = $this->Users->get($this->Auth->user('id'));
    if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
      $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
      if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('Your account has been edited'));
        return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'edit']);
      }
      $this->Flash->error(__('Your account could not be edited. Please fix errors below.'));
    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
}
```

And in my edit.ctp file:

```
<?php
    $this->Form->templates($form_templates['defaultBootstrap']);
    echo $this->Form->create($user);
?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Edit Profile'); ?></legend>
    <?php
      echo $this->Form->input('email', [
        'label' => __('Email'),
            'placeholder' => __('Email'),
            'autofocus'
        ]);
        echo $this->Form->input('currency', [
          'label' => __('Default Currency'),
          'options' => [
             'CAD' => 'CAD',
             'USD' => 'USD'
           ]
        ]);
        echo $this->Form->input('password', array(
          'label' => __('Password'),
          'placeholder' => __('Password'),
          'value' => ''
        ));
        echo $this->Form->input('confirm_password', array(
          'label' => __('Confirm Password'),
          'placeholder' => __('Confirm Password'),
          'type' => 'password'
        ));
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->submit(__('Edit'));
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

The problem with this is that the password that gets attached to the form is hashed, so when I use patchEntity, it gets hashed again, because of this in the entity User.php:

```
protected function _setPassword($password) {
  return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
}
```

I've also tried this by not grabbing the password when I set $user in my controller. But then when I use patchEntity it just hashes the blank value instead.

Maybe I'm going about this the entirely wrong way, I'm just looking for some direction on how to tackle this if anyone can help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to have the ability to change the password in the `edit` form, then you'll have to make sure that it is being dropped before it is being marshalled in case no data is being provided.

This can be achieved using the `Model.beforeMarshal` event in your `Users` table class.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#before-marshal

```
public function beforeMarshal(Event $event, \ArrayObject $data, \ArrayObject $options)
{
    if(isset($data['password']) && empty($data['password'])) {
        unset($data['password']);
    }
}
```

This is a very basic example, you may want to add some more strict checks, maybe remove whitespaces before testing the value for being empty, etc

You could also separate editing profile data and editing credentials into different actions/views/forms, and then use the `fieldList` option to restrict the fields that can be marshalled.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#avoiding-property-mass-assignment-attacks

Edit profile:

```
$this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data, [
    'fieldList' => ['currency']
]);
```

Edit credentials:

```
$this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data, [
    'fieldList' => ['email', 'password']
]);
```

Comment: You say "if you need to have the ability", as if it's an odd request to allow users to change their password? Should I be going about this differently?

Comment: @ArakTai'Roth It's not odd to let user change their passwords, it's just that often editing credentials and profile data is separated into different forms/sections of an application, like "change your profile" and "change your login".

Comment: Is there a reason that that's a better idea, or does it matter?

Comment: @ArakTai'Roth It's just another way to avoid problems like the one that you are facing, other than that it's probably mostly personal preference, unless the app has any specific requirements regarding this.

Comment: I added a little bit to my question in regards to your second option of splitting the profile data and the credentials. Perhaps you can add to your answer, if you know?

Comment: The best approach IMO is still to use alias fields to avoid accidental overwriting as outlined [here](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/). The behavior is also available for 3.x and keeps things DRY.